# Decrement float but ensure minimum zero and not negative

Tags: mysql

How do I decrement a float value but ensure it has a minimum of zero? Without an additional query.

```
$query = "UPDATE accounts SET credits = credits - 1 WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{
    $statement->bind_param("i", $id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->close();
}
```

I saw an example for integer values, but not floats.

To be clear a value of 0.23, it will go to zero.

Comment: What example did you see for integers and why won't it work with floats?

Comment: They set a condition like "where credits >= 1"

Comment: And why do you think that wouldn't work here? Also, can there be more than one matching row? If not, what's the limit for?

Comment: Well I need a value like 0.123 to go to 0 and I doubt a condition would do that. I always limit my update queries because I operate with large tables and need to protect my data.

Comment: Limiting queries doesn't protect anything. If you have a faulty query, it'll limit the extent of the damage. But the best way to not run faulty queries is not to write them.

Comment: What about the scope of damage from sql injection, or team members that haven't had their morning coffee yet? I'm interested, can you tell me the disadvantage for using LIMIT 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function to limit the minimum to zero:

```
$query = "UPDATE accounts SET credits = GREATEST(credits - 1, 0) WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
```

This way decrementing into negative territory will never happen.

Comment: That looks awesome, I had no idea there was a greatest function for updates :))

Comment: @AmyNeville Sure! Most functions that work in `select` are also available in `update`, `insert` and `delete`, although one tends to use them mostly in `select` queries.

Answer (score -1):

This works for float also. Cannot find a reason why it will not work on your side.

```
UPDATE accounts  
SET credits = credits - 1
WHERE id = $number
and credits > 0
```